# Help with differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wonder if someone could help me solve this equation:

$$M x^2x'x''-B x'+ Ax^2(x'')^2 = 0$$

where $M, B$ and $A$ are real constants.

Comment: sorry if it is not clear, I am new and I don't know writing properly.

Comment: M B and A are real constants and the equation is x squared multiplied by the derivative of x multiplied by the double derivative of x minus B multiplied by the derivative of x plus A multiplied by x squared multiplied by the double derivative of x squared

Comment: yea that's it but just at the end you have x square, not x elevated at the third power

Comment: How can I make not to write formulas like a noob?

Comment: You can click edit and see what I did. Also, see mathJax tutorial (FAQ). Are the equations correct?

Comment: What do you expect as a solution? Multiply with $4A$ to get the completed square $$(2Axx''+Mxx')^2=4ABx'+M^2x^2x'^2$$ which allows to isolate the second derivative in two valid variants. Another way is to compute the next derivative to get a unique value for the third derivative where the choice of branch lies in the choice of the initial value of the second derivative which is still a solution of the quadratic equation. With that you then can compute numerical solutions.